# Downloading file from server over FTP

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, cmd, remote-access

I need to download a file that is placed in a folder called abc_20140221_123456 in server1 over ftp to my local directory. The problem is that the **last six characters of the folder name are not fixed.** For example today the folder may be called abc_20140221_123456 and tomorrow it might be called abc_20140221_234567. I am having problems in writing an automation batch script to do the same.

Here's the script I am working on:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set buildDate=%DATE:~0,10%
set dateStr=%buildDate:~6,4%%buildDate:~3,2%%buildDate:~0,2%
set folderName=abc_%dateStr%_
echo open server1>>file.tmp 
echo username>>file.tmp
echo password>>file.tmp
echo prompt>> file.tmp
echo binary>>file.tmp
echo lcd E:\>>file.tmp
:: Not sure how to cd to abc_20140221_* from here
echo get filename.txt>>file.tmp
echo y>>file.tmp
echo disconnect>>file.tmp
echo bye>>file.tmp
ftp -i -s:file.tmp
pause
```

I know that I can loop through directories using for like this:

```
for /d %%d in (' %path%/*%folderName%* ') do (
echo get filename.txt>>file.tmp
echo y>>file.tmp
)
```

But "for" doesn't work inside ftp>.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does `cd abc_20140221_*` work in your FTP server?  The usual way will be to open a connection and log a `dir` command to a text file and then parse the text file for the folder name - and create a script on the fly to open a new connection for the download.

Comment: I just tried doing that, but cd abc_20140221_* doesn't work in the ftp prompt. 

I understand what you are trying to say. But is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: No, as FTP doesn't provide a way to change folder via wildcards as you have tried.  You might be able to use a third party FTP tool which has extra features such as this, but Windows FTP is limited.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that for a given date there is only one abc_YYYYMMDD_nnnnnn directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set buildDate=%DATE:~0,10%
set dateStr=%buildDate:~6,4%%buildDate:~3,2%%buildDate:~0,2%
set folderName=abc_%dateStr%_
set root=E:
echo open server1>file.tmp 
echo username>>file.tmp
echo password>>file.tmp
echo prompt>> file.tmp
echo binary>>file.tmp
for /D %%D in (%root%\%foldername%??????) do set target=%%D
echo lcd %target%>>file.tmp
echo get filename.txt>>file.tmp
echo y>>file.tmp
echo disconnect>>file.tmp
echo bye>>file.tmp
ftp -i -s:file.tmp
pause
```

I set `root` to `E:\` based on your original script - you can change it to whatever the actual parent directory is. I also changed

```
echo open server1>>file.tmp
```

to

```
echo open server1>file.tmp
```

so it creates a new temp file. Otherwise, it will keep appending to file.tmp each time the script runs. If that is what you want, or if you are generating a unique script file name each time and were just using file.tmp as a placeholder, ignore that change and use `>>` as before.

If there is more than one folder for a given day, I believe this script will use whichever one comes up last when the wildcards are expanded. I did not test this out, however.